# Image processing for detect balloon

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, beagleboneblack

I want to do a project of image recognize by a camera of a balloon in movement.
In addition to knowing the location of the balloon.
so my question is which microcontroller is capable of dealing with?

Comment: You'd have a pretty hard time of it trying to interface a camera, handle the memory you need for image processing and writing the code without any decent libraries on any microcontroller like Arduino, so I'd look at Raspberry Pi. If you don't need super high performance, Raspberry Pi Zero is great and cheap, else Rasperry Pi 3. OpenCV runs on there too as does Numpy, so you can develop your code almost anywhere too. Plus you have WIFi to send the results of your processing to somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a raspberry pi or boards like orange pi, or anything more powerful than that. Otherwise, you will have a hard time dealing with hardware limitations as well as finding/writing appropriate libraries for low-level hardware like Arduino.
Moreover, consider using a laptop running Linux.
Just to clarify, I am not saying that is not possible to do it using Arduino, I just not recommend it if either you are not a professional or you do not have adequate time.